# Extract string between html tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to extract a string from html tags

```
<title>what i want</title>
```

I know there are other simiral or even identical questions answered but the answers on those don't seem to work on me. My current code is

```
String html = wc.DownloadString("URL");
Match m = Regex.Match(html, "<title>(.*)</title>", RegexOptions.Singleline); 
MessageBox(m.Value);
```

This outputs

```
<title>what i want</title>
```

Not

```
what i want
```

Note that i have used other regural expressions from different answers and got the same result
I am also not familiar with regural expressions so this may be a noob question.

Comment: You need an HTML parser.

Comment: sorry its c# just edited

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298353/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-strong-tags-usings-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get website title from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329307/how-to-get-website-title-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `m.Groups[1].Value` ([documentation for Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)), or `m.Result("$1")` ([documentation for Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.result(v=vs.110).aspx)); either should work.

The object `m` which was returned by `Regex.Match` is an object that contains various pieces of information about what was matched.  This includes both the entire string that was matched, including in this case the title tags themselves, and the parts of the string matched by each group of parentheses.  `m.Value` gives the entire string; `m.Groups[1].Value` gives the part matched by the first group, `m.Groups[2].Value` gives the part matched by the second group, etc.  This has to be done outside the regular expression because a program might want more than one group; for instance, if you're matching a time of day, like `(\d+):(\d+)`, then you might want to assign the hours (`m.Groups[1].Value`) to one variable and the minutes (`m.Groups[2].Value`) to a different variable.

Comment: I thought this was a regural expression problem, how does the `Groups[].Value` cut out the tags?(it works thanks a lot)

Comment: @harambe The object that was returned includes both the entire string matched and the part matched by each group of parentheses.  `m.Value` is how you get the entire string matched, and `m.Groups` is how you get the part in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = m.Groups[1].Value;
```